# How to interpret coefficients of a cross-lagged panel analysis

Tags: self-study, experiment-design, structural-equation-modeling

I'm trying to understand the coefficients of this cross-lagged panel analysis.
Are they correlation coefficients? are they regression coefficients?
I'm not sure how can I interpret them if I have no idea of which is the maximum reachable (for example: are .907 very high? if it is a correlation yes but if it is a regression not necessarily)

There is a note indicating: "Standardized WLSMV estimates. WLSMV = Weighted least squares estimator."

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are regression coefficients.

If you have no missing data, you can reproduce almost all of those results with two regression analyses, or one multivariate regression.

Comment: Even the bidirectional arrows?

Comment: The bidirectional arrows are correlations / covariances, or partial correlations / covariances. I should have said that - you need a separate analysis if you want them (they're not usually something people are very interested in - in the same way that manova doesn't report them.)